# Anyone have any recommendations for ANY .net hosting that supports 'full trust'?

Tags: hosting, asp.net, .net, cloud

We have been using Mosso / The Rackspace Cloud until very recently, and am generally impressed with their systems and support, but they have suddenly switched to a medium trust model for .NET for newly added sites.

We can't get our [CMS (Sitefinity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061680/any-hints-on-getting-sitefinity-cms-to-work-on-medium-trust) to work in this environment.

They will also be migrating existing server clusters to medium trust, so we will have to move several sites away from them before that happens.

Does anyone have any recommendations for <strike>cloud / load balanced / server farm</strike> **ANY** .NET hosting supporting full trust?

Rgds
Damian

Answer (score 2):

[AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com/) runs applications in full trust per default. AppHarbor is a fully managed and scalable .NET cloud platform. I needed, your application can be deployed to multiple instances, and the platform will transparently loadbalance between them.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)

Answer (score 1):

I used [1and1 VPS Server Hosting](http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/VpsWindows;jsessionid=432431A916F944CBA113EF9F71A8BA12.TC61a?__frame=_top&__lf=Static) for over a year with great success.  Their pricing is great (starting at $29 per month) and the up time was near perfect.  Best part is you can load almost anything you want (other than anything with kernel level drivers).  ...And no, I don't work for them...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with our provider, and ended up moving to a Godaddy Windows 2003 VPS (virtual private server). It was around $35/mo., but we had remote RDP login to the box so we could do whatever we wanted.

Your app is probably more secure anyway with a situation where other users don't have Full Trust, as I assume they made the change due to security concerns. So if you do find a provider that allows this, you may find your app hacked in the future by one of their other clients.

Comment: Yes, to some extent I agree.  The trade off was with the load balancing / ability to scale Mosso's cloud provided.

Answer (score 0):

I personally will give [**ASPHostCentral**](http://www.asphostcentral.com) a try-out as their hosting packages are very attractive and reasonable. Moreover, I can find the feature "full trust setting" on all their hosting plans and this will certainly convince me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-up-vote the comment supporting www.webhost4life.com. They are my current choice for hosting, I have been using their services for over five years now. They support full trust for .Net applications, and I have been very happy with the support provided.